# device-mapper: reload ioctl on osprober-linux-nvme0n1p7 failed: Device or resource busy

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, bugs, ioctl

I ran into the error

> device-mapper: reload ioctl on osprober-linux-nvme0n1p7  failed: Device or resource busy

while compiling the kernel in Ubuntu Studio. I use ZFS for my main drive.

Apparently, this is a bug: [[zfs-root] "device-mapper: reload ioctl on osprober-linux-sdaX failed: Device or resource busy" against devices owned by ZFS](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober/+bug/1848496).

How can I work around it?

Comment: I updated today, and since then I have the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the launchpad thread you linked to, it is a cosmetic error caused by `os-prober` not properly ignoring ZFS-managed drives, and if you're not dual-booting you can safely make the message go away with `apt purge os-prober`. See also [here](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/9801).